# How to use Like function with current date in SQL

Tags: mysql

Hi i am trying to execute below query but it is not executing using CURDATE function with LIKE

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Today Un-Subscription'
FROM events
where eventName='unsubscribed'
AND eventDate LIKE 'CURDATE()'
```

Comment: Single quoted strings are just text, not code. What are you trying to accomplish? Trying to handle dates as text normally makes it harder and slower.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. `LIKE` is a string operator not a date operator. Your question is unclear. [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables and/or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites, make sure the statements are complete and compile, don't post just mere snippets), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: `LIKE` without a wildcard is simply a `=`. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Side note: Don't get used to use single quotes for identifiers such as column aliases. Yes, sadly MySQL accepts that, but in SQL single quotes are usually for string (or date...) literals. Should you ever use another DBMS (or future MySQL versions become more sane about this) you'll likely get an error. Use backticks for identifiers that have special characters in them or are case sensitive or preferably don't use special characters and case sensitive identifiers at all. Identifiers don't need to be "pretty", "pretty" headers and such are a job for the presentation layer.

Comment: My expectation is that query run and automatically get current date and time
In my db the date format is this 2022-01-07 10:55:58

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that query?

Comment: Use `.. AND eventDate >= CURRENT_DATE AND eventDate < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY`. This will count today's amount.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as 'Today Un-Subscription'
FROM events
where eventName='unsubscribed'
AND DATE_FORMAT(eventDate , "%Y") = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(), "%Y")
```

(fit format string to your needs!)

"like" is not required because you can strip the time/date parts with the format however you can use it if eventDate is not a date type.

Comment: My expectation is that query run and automatically get current date and time
In my db the date format is this 2022-01-07 10:55:58

Comment: So just remove the single quotes and change `LIKE` to `=`

Comment: I canceled my downvote. I downvoted because your answer prior to the edit was not an answer.

Comment: Using a function on a column prevents the use of indexes on it. You shouldn't do it like that. Use a range like `eventdate >= <lower bound, inclusive> AND eventdate < <upper bound, exclusive>` instead.